# Connection to Azure Service bus works for 5 minutes and then it does not work for 5 minutes

Tags: https, azureservicebus, abap

I'm trying to connect to a cloud based (Azure) Service Bus. It is from a SAP/ABAP system directly to Service Bus on port 443.

The problem is that the communication works good sometimes, and not so good sometimes.
After some analysis we set up a monitoring batch job sending one request every minute: It seems that the communciation works fine for about 5 requests (minutes) and then to be down for another 5 requests (minutes). Then it works fine for 5 new minutes and so on.

During the time the communication is working we are able to send HTTPS requests to Service bus, while the communication is down we get a HTTP 404 and SM59 transaction in SAP shows: Direct connect to xxx failed: NIECONN_REFUSED(-10).

The strange thing is that if we login to the source machine and do a telnet to the service bus, the connection starts to work again immediately for another 5 minutes. Same thing happens of we flush/reset the DNS cache in SAP. However, the servicebus never changes IP so it unclear why that makes the connection to work for 5 new minutes.

Other components in Azure works totally fine, we're only experiencing this issue with Service Bus. Does anyone know if there is something changing in Service Bus after 5 minutes or have experienced something similar?

Comment: Maybe you can add proxy (for example nginx) to connection and try to get more log. Maybe microsoft firewall block your system.

Comment: I have to admit that I have zero experience with Azure, but I would see if I can find any server-sided logs which might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: This could be useful for you ... https://github.com/microsoft/ABAP-SDK-for-Azure ... it may not solve your problem but you're removed from the direct connection components and may help.